# Node Js read last line of a text file outputs Object Promise

Tags: html, node.js

I have a local server running with Node Js. On my first page the user inputs a user ID and I save it on a text file. On the next page I would like to append the userID to a text file together with some other information. I'm using the option to read just the last line, so I append the right user ID and not all of the inputed IDs for example. When I log the last line to the console it outputs it correctly. The problem is when I try to append it to the new text file it shows as: "[object Promise]" and doesn't show the user ID (whereas the rest of the information is appended correctly).

```
app.post('/userID', function(req, res){

  var userID= req.body.userID + ';' + '\n';
  var data = fs.appendFileSync('userID.txt', userID, 'utf8');

  return res.sendfile('main.html');
});


app.post('/submit', function(req, res){

  var id = readLastLines.read('userID.txt', 1);
  var option = [ req.body.option],
  var toADD = fs.readFile('data/data1.txt','utf-8',(err, file) => fs.appendFileSync('output.txt',file.split('\n').map( (line) =>
            id + line + option.shift()).join('\n'),(err) => {}
              ));

  res.sendfile('main2.html');
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it the `/submit` route that is a appending ?

Comment: @Pogrindis Yes, it's the /submit.

Answer (score 0):

So, the return value of `.map` is a promise that is fulfilled with an array of the mapped values.

That's probably why you are seeing the `[object Promise]` being added, it has not resolved at write time.

You can try to space it out a bit for clarity, but something like the following :

```
var option = [ req.body.option],
var toADD = fs.readFile('data/data1.txt','utf-8',(err, file) => fs.appendFileSync('output.txt',file.split('\n').map( (line) =>
        id + line + option.shift()).then((res)=>{
            res.join('\n'),(err) => {};
            return res;
            })
        ));
```

Basically, the `map` method is being written to the file, but it itself is a promise object, this needs to be resolved first before appending.

I haven't tested the above code yet, but I will shortly when I get a chance.